# Play - Execute an sql statement without writing the database configuration in application.conf

Tags: mysql, scala, playframework, database-connection, config

I am writing a scala application using the Playframework. I don't want to write the database configuration in the **application.conf** file. Instead I have a function similar to the one given below. I want to send the configuration parameters as arguments of a function. Then I want create a connection and execute the statement. BTW, the database is a mysql database.

```
def run_sql(sql: String, host: String, user: String, pass: String, port: String, dbname: String): Unit = {

    // **** create the connection ****

    DB.withConnection {
      conn =>
        {
          val statement = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY)
          try {
            statement.execute(sql)
          }
          catch {
            case e: Exception => Logger.warn("Error executing DML %s. %s".format(sql, e.getMessage))
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible? If so then how? I hope I have made my question clear. If you have any confusion please ask. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`// **** create the connection ****`

here we can write

```
val driver = Play.current.configuration.getString("rds.driver").getOrElse("")
val host = Play.current.configuration.getString("rds.host").getOrElse("")
val port = Play.current.configuration.getString("rds.port").getOrElse("")
val user = Play.current.configuration.getString("rds.user").getOrElse("")
val password = Play.current.configuration.getString("rds.password").getOrElse("")
val url = "mysql://" + user + ":" + password + "@" + host + ":" + port + "/" + dbname

// there's probably a better way to do this

Class.forName(driver)
val connection: Connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password)
```